# Twitter upload media returns status code 400

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am trying to upload an image to twitter account using twitter's media upload api. I am using `node-twitter` module for nodejs.

This is the code i am using

```
fs.writeFile("out.png", base64String, 'base64', function (err) {
                console.log(err);                
            });

var data = fs.readFileSync("out.png");

// Make post request on media endpoint. Pass file data as media parameter
client.post('media/upload', {media: data}, function(error, media, response){

  if (!error) {

    // If successful, a media object will be returned.
    console.log(media);

    // Lets tweet it
    var status = {
      status: 'I am a tweet',
      media_ids: media.media_id_string // Pass the media id string
    }

    client.post('statuses/update', status, function(error, tweet, response){
      if (!error) {
        console.log(tweet);
      }
    });

  }
  else{
     console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Response code 400 stands for "Bad request" therefor I assume that format of your post is wrong, most-likely the way you load your image. Just try to remove that

```
fs.writeFile("out.png", base64String, 'base64', function (err) {
                console.log(err);                
            });
```

Because it is trying to write file rather than read it from your disk

Comment: I have a base64 string so i save it in png so that i can use that png to upload to twiter

Comment: You could try your function with a regular image in png format just to see if its actually problem with the Post method or is it a problem with your image

Comment: Print following output in the console when using regular image

`<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 f9 00 00 02 3a 08 02 00 00 00 32 a2 c0 35 00 00 00 64 7a 54 58 74 52 61 77 20 70 72 6f 66 69 ... >
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }`

Comment: try adding more information to your console.log() so you would know where this is coming from such as console.log('this is coming from error'+error); and console.log('successful tweet'+tweet); but it seems that you're getting to error block, which means theres something wrong with your request. Make sure you have correct credentials and api key for your twitter account

Comment: Uploading a regular image worked(Previously it was not uploading due to slow internet connection). How can i make it work with base64 encoded images.

Comment: I wouldn't know as I have never worked with these technologies, but I assume there must be a way to save your picture in a regular format and then upload it to twitter? After short research I found that [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267939/nodejs-write-base64-image-file) might help you to solve the problem that you're after, best of luck!