# How to copy\move an image from one directory to another using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filereader

I have made a chat application in node JS and JavaScript. I am giving user a free hand to upload their picture for profile.

I am using Node JS `mv` module and trying to move or copy a file user select, to my specific directory. I am using `Socket.io` to communicate with node.

The problem is, I am using an `input[type=file]` when a user select an image file, I get the `value` of this image file.

This is what I get in return: `C:\fakepath\image.png`.

When I pass it to the `mv` method, it throw an error: `No such directory`, because of the `fakepath`. I tried to get the real path of my file to pass it to the `mv` method, so that it can move the file to the directory I want. I tried using `FileReader()` and then invoked `fr.readAsDataURL(file);` and it returns the below text :

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAMAA...... // shortened
```

**This is my Javascript**

```
var file_inp = document.getElementById("upl_img");
   file_inp.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{

      if('files' in file_inp){
         if(file_inp.files.length==0){
            alert("Select an Image to upload !");
         }else{

            var file = file_inp.files[0];
            var fr = new FileReader();
              console.log(file_inp.value);

            if(file){
              fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

            fr.onloadend = ()=>{
              console.log(fr.result)
              socket.emit("upload_image",{path:fr.result,name:file_inp.files[0].name,size:file_inp.files[0].size})
            }

         }
      }

   })
```

**This is the node script**

```
socket.on("upload_image",(data)=>{

    mv(data.path, './user_images', function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('File Moved ! ')          
    });             

})
```

**Note:** **I only need to move the file to the `user_images` directory, when the user select a picture.**

Comment: If this is a Node server communicating with a browser, there's probably no need to use `mv`, just [write the DataURL to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20272545/726766) using the native `fs` module.

Comment: yes @shennan but mv is easier a bit

Comment: [mv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv) writes files, not DataURL's. So in this case it's not easier. It's the wrong tool for the wrong job.

Comment: so fs is a good tool for it ! @shennan

Comment: `fs` can write buffers to disk, and as I said in my previous comment; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20272545/726766) shows you how to convert a DataURL image into a buffer.