# Resizing image with busboy and sharp in firebase cloud function/Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, busboy, sharp

Having a problem when uploading to firebase cloud functions.. I'm using busboy and sharp to achieve this but every time I run my code it only return "finished with status: 'timeout'" with no error...

this code will work without the sharp resize function  please see below code for reference.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const Busboy = require("busboy");
const config = require('../config');
const gcs = config.get('gcs');
const UUID = require('uuidv4')
const sharp = require('sharp');


 let insertStorageMaterials = (req,callback) =>{
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  let uploadData = null;
  let origFileName;

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    origFileName = filename
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
    uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

  });

  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
    let uuid = UUID();

    sharp(uploadData.file)
    .resize(500, 500)
    .toFile(uploadData.file)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("data",data)
      bucket
      .upload(uploadData.file, {
        uploadType: "media",
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: uploadData.type,
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
          }
        },
        destination:"Materials/test/"+origFileName  
    })
    return data
  }).then(data=>{
      let file = data[0];
      let dataURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket.name + "/o/" + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + "?alt=media&token=" + uuid;
      console.log("url",dataURL)
      return callback(false,{dataURL:dataURL,name:origFileName,message:"Success!"});
    .catch(error =>{
      return error;
    })
  })

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);

  }

module.exports = {
  insertStorageMaterials:insertStorageMaterials
}
```

express call

```
//index.js
const app = express();
const appUsers = require('./Routes/userRoute')

const api = fbFunc.https.onRequest(app);

app.post(['/uploadMaterials'],appUsers);


module.exports = {api}

//Routes
const userFunc = require('../Functions/userFunc')

apiCalls.post('/uploadMaterials',(req,res)=>{
    userFunc.uploadMaterials(req,(err,result)=>{
      if (err) return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
      return res.status(200).send(result);
  })
})
```

EDIT:

```
  sharp(uploadData.file)
    .resize(500, 500)
    .toFile(uploadData.file)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("datadddd",data)
      return bucket
      .upload(uploadData.file, {
        uploadType: "media",
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: uploadData.type,
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
          }
        },
        destination:"Materials/test/"+origFileName  
    })

  .then(data=>{
      let file = data[0];
      let dataURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket.name + "/o/" + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + "?alt=media&token=" + uuid;
      console.log("url",dataURL)
      return callback(false,{dataURL:dataURL,name:origFileName,message:"Success!"});
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      return error;
    })

}).catch(error =>{
  return error;
})
  })
```

Comment: Where is your function definition?  It looks like you're not showing the whole thing.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited my answer is that enough info? Thanks!

Comment: It might actually need more time.  You can increase the timeout/memory limits [in the console](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the issue is for the resize API, but did you try using toBuffer method instead of toFile?

```
sharp(input)
    .resize(500, 500)
    .toBuffer()
    .then(data => {
    // Convert data to image file
    });
```

You can convert the image buffer to file using the accepted answer here - [NodeJS write base64 image-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267939/nodejs-write-base64-image-file)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP functions terminate when you send a response back to the client.  Since you're never sending a response, the function will just time out waiting for that response.  Use that `res` object that Express is passing to your code.

Comment: I do send something back to the client, just didn't include it earlier, like i said it does work without the sharp library.

Comment: It's impossible to tell because you're still not showing the entire code.  You're omitted parts of it, and I can't see how it all fits together.

Comment: I've added everything now.

Comment: I'd guess you're still not returning a result because you're not dealing with promises correctly.  I don't think your `return data` line is doing what you expect.  Think carefully about how data flows through your function, and add debug logs everywhere to see what's not being invoked.

Comment: Each then() should return a value or throw this shows if i remove the return data; but I don't want to return anything until the upload is finish. any suggestion how should i do that?

Comment: upload() returns another promise, doesn't it?

Comment: you mean I should return the bucket.upload? please see the edit part if I'm doing it correctly.. tried that and it does not work.. :(

Comment: Have you tried adding debug logging to make sure all the values are what you expect at every step?

Comment: When I say "at every step", I mean throughout your code to make sure all values are what you expect.  I can't really go back and forth debugging your code with you - you'll need to identify a specific issue that you don't understand or are unable to debug further.